# grub_script.yy.c:2354:13: error: 'yy_fatal_error' defined but not used

Tags: makefile, bison, flex-lexer, grub, gnu-make

When building the latest grub2 (2.00) I get this error.

I have tried adding `-Wno-unused-function` to both `HOST_CFLAGS`, `HOST_CPPFLAGS`, `TARGET_CPPFLAGS` and `TARGET_CFLAGS` in the `Makefile`. I even tried deleting that function whilst `make` was running!

Unfortunately the error remains.

Comment: Please list versions of: flex, bison, automake, autoconf. And operating system wouldn't hurt to know either.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 liveusb chrooting into a 14.04 partition (all amd64) with freetype-2.5.3, bison-3.0, grub-2.00, libfreetype6_2.5.2-1, flex-2.5.39, libfreetype6-dev_2.5.2-1 and m4-1.4.17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2012-08/msg00006.html)?

> The latest `flex` makes the `GRUB-2.00` build fail. I can work around the issues with `--disable-werror`, but `grub-core/script/yylex.l` causes two warnings that do not work with -Werror.
>
> `./grub-core/script/yylex.l: At top level:
>   grub_script.yy.c:2351:13: error: 'yy_fatal_error' defined but not used`
>
> This can be fixed by removing `#define YY_FATAL_ERROR(msg)` in `yylex.l`.

However, according to [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-grub/2014-05/msg00003.html) post this seems to have been fixed.

Judging from the info on the net you either want to switch to `grub 2.02` or try an older version of `flex`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the commit (from the mailing-list): http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=9cc836a27be4a95f6f7bfd5b6bc099801645c0ea